# Files repeatedly downloaded form same IP - suggestions?

Tags: ip-blocking

I have a few files that can be downloaded from my website. Every few hours all files are downloaded from the same IP address (98.137.207.97 - might be Yahoo?). How should I proceed? Should I just block the IP (and hope the downloads are not taken up by another IP) or are there better ways to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

You should create a [robot.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/) file if you don't want bots/spiders/etc to be crawling certain parts of your site.